# Casting in a compound assignment operator?

Tags: c++

I have code that, reduced to its essence, comes down to:

```
int x = 5;
x *= 0.5;
```

Compiling this with Visual Studio, I get a warning C4244 about possible loss of data - of course, because (simplified) the multiplication of an int by a double results in a double which is then cast to an int, losing the non-integer part.

My question is, is there C++ syntax to indicate that this the intended behavior, so as to silence the warning (I know about pragma push/pop to disable the warning, I think it's clearer to indicate that this is actually intended behavior, and that I'm not just suppressing warnings).

The long-form would be to cast explicitly after the multiplication like so:

```
x = (int)(x * 0.5);
```

but the compound-operator notation is easier to read.

So, is there a way to cast like this? I've tried putting "(int)" in every location I could think of, but none of them seem to be valid C++ :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure to get rid of the warning you need to switch to something else (e.g., `x /= 2;` or `x >>= 1;`).

Comment: Is it always `0.5`? Why aren't you using an integer division if you are not interested in the fractional part?

Comment: The C++ way would be `x = static_cast<int>(x * 0.5)` by the way.  Parenthetical casts should be discouraged in C++.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I wouldn't use the right-shift (the OP is using a signed type and if `x < 0` the behavior becomes implementation-defined).

Comment: The compiler will use a shift where appropriate.  Just write the most natural thing (which is `x /= 2;` for division).

Comment: @dirkgently: I assumed the `int` was only an example, and he might be dealing with a `unsigned` at times -- but yes, if you're dealing only with `int`, `/=` is undoubtedly preferred. Whether you ever use `>>=` depends mostly on whether the intent is really division, or this might be something like a bitmask, and he started with division as a way of implementing what was really intended as a bit-shift.

Comment: It's not always * 0.5, the actual code multiplies by a variable of type double, the example is just the smallest example that shows the issue.

Comment: @Roel: I think you need to worry about your rounding behavior (particularly if you are dealing with negative numbers). See my answer to get some idea of what rounding is.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of multiplying by 0.5, divide by 2. With two `int`s integer division will be used and there will be no warning.

And if you really want to multiply by floats/doubles, don't use `int` to store the result.

Comment: With a constant divisor, integer division should not be used by any decent optimizer.

Comment: I don't always multiply by 0.5, that's just an example, the multiplication can be with any double value. It's stored in an int because that is the type of a member in a class in a third-party library I'm using. I appreciate that you're taking the time to post, undoubtedly with the intent to help, but it's rather tiring on Stackoverflow that I need to spell out every objection or workaround I already thought of myself but don't want to use (for whatever reason) in a question, and still people assume that I'm retarded and that I don't realize that * 0.5 == / 2.

Comment: @Roel: It's also very tiring to guess every silly restriction the OP might have this time. Include all relevant information in the post. If you really want to use `int`, explicit casting is the only option left.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I mean semantically, not in a micro-performance kind of way.

Comment: @Roel So, you prefer to waste everyone else's time *guessing* your requirements?

Comment: Sorry for sounding frustrated, it's because I was ;) Again, I appreciate your time trying to help, my question was: is there a way to avoid the warning in this specific notation. @Martinho: no, that's exactly what I don't want, which is why I provided an abstract example and was only looking for an answer to my question, not speculation into what my intent is, and offering workarounds. Either way, sorry if I caused offense, didn't set out to do so. I guess the answer to my question is 'no, it can't be done'.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is in place - you should be warned of the possible loss of data.

Any ways to avoid the warning involves using a syntax which clearly expresses your intent. This can be done in the following ways:

1. Create a function which does what you want.
2. Do not use the unary operator. Instead, use the binary operator, and explicitly truncate the result: `x = static_cast<int>(x * 0.5);`

With the unary operator `*` you cannot suppress the warning easily because that operator was intended to be user in a clear and straighforward way, with no casting involved - and your case does not fulfill this requirement. So it is a *good* thing that you cannot do it.

Comment: +1 for "Create a function which does what you want".  The ugly cast, along with any rounding logic can then be hidden, the calling code just sees a short descriptive name, such as `rescale` or `multiply_by`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's comments, you are probably best advised to use an appropriate function from `<cmath>` depending on the sort of *rounding behavior* you want (biased/un-biased).

For example `floor` typically does biased rounding (biased towards negative infinity, because it always chooses the lower integer number) i.e. `floor( -7.5 )` would give you `-8` and you will need to roll-your-own should you want a symmetric rounding i.e. want `floor( -7.5 )` to be `-7` (as `floor( 7.5 )` gives `7`).

`round` however can be tweaked to produce an unbiased rounding. Typically, it would produce `10` from `round( 10.3 )`, `11` from `round( 10.6 )` (or greater). There is still the problem with rounding at the middle ([tie-breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking)) i.e. what `round( 10.5 )` should provide (it would typically produce `11`). In case, this behavior is not suitable for you, you may want to look up at some alternatives like [*Banker's Rounding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)/[*Alternate Rounding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Alternating_tie-breaking) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a **multiplication of an int and a float is a float**.

If you want to convert the int to a float, you are likely to need to round the float to remove the decimal value. If you simply cast it, you can have rounding errors.

For example this function does rounding (there are other way of rounding numbers):

```
int round(float x)
{
  return static_cast<int>((x > 0.5) ? ceil(x) : floor(x));
}
```

Then you just have to call it that way:

```
  int x = 5;
  float y = 0.33f;
  x = round(x * y);
```

And you have **no warnings** and the **float is properly rounded and cast to an int**.

I don't have a proper solution for the `*=` operator with a good rounding, so with this solution you will have to replace the `*=`.