# Is gcc's -Wconversion incompatible with the use of compound assignment (+= etc.) with integral types shorter than int?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, casting, warnings

gcc has a useful flag `-Wconversion` that produces a warning when there's an implicit conversion from a wider to a narrower type, potentially losing information. Unfortunately, it has the following ... unhelpful ... behaviour.

---

Consider this program:

```
int main(void) {
  short x = 1;
  x = x+x;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with -Wconversion produces

```
nonsense.c: In function 'main':
nonsense.c:3:8: warning: conversion to 'short int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

which is fair enough; on most platforms this will do something you might not expect if it happens that `x==0x8000`. (The actual mechanism by which you get this warning: the operands to `+` are subject to the "usual arithmetic conversions", which widens them to int; so the result is also of type int; then assigning back to `x` is an implicit conversion from a wider to a narrower type.) But suppose you *do* expect and intend this behaviour. (You're simulating a 16-bit processor, or a 16-bit shift register; or you know the range of possible values of `x` in this code and it'll never overflow.) You can tell the compiler by putting in an explicit cast:

```
int main(void) {
  short x = 1;
  x = (short)(x+x);
  return 0;
}
```

and it then won't complain.

---

So far, so good. But if the assignment that's causing the trouble is a compound assignment -- `+=`, `*=`, `<<=`, etc. -- then so far as I can see there is *no way to get rid of this warning* because there isn't any point in the code at which you could insert the explicit cast.

This means, for instance, that you can't have all of

- -Wconversion in your project's top-level compiler flags, to catch all the real mistakes it's intended for.
- Any instance anywhere in the code of compound assignment operators applied to integral types shorter than `int`.
- A warning-free build.

which seems sad.

---

So, the question: **is there a good way to work around this?** I can see the following ways:

- Use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ...` to disable the warning in bits of code that are known to provoke it despite not having bugs. (*Downside*: ugly, compiler-specific.)
- Expand compound assignments into longer single assignments and insert explicit casts. (*Downside*: super-ugly.)
- Turn off `-Wconversion`. (*Downside*: This warning is useful elsewhere.)
- Put up with the warnings. (*Downside*: Incompatible with using `-Werror`; in any case it's good practice to make your code compile with no warnings at all, because the difference between "no warnings" and "some warnings" is easier to spot than the difference between "some warnings" and "some more warnings".)

All of these seem unsatisfactory, and I'm wondering whether there's something cleverer that I'm missing.

(Note: of course I will accept a "no, that's it" answer if that's actually the truth.)

---

So, it looks as if the answer is that this really is the intended behaviour and there is no way to stop it that's much better than the ones listed above. (Mark B observed that you can write a function that does the same as `+=` but with explicit casting. ecatmur proposed defining a new type with `operator+=` functions to do the explicit casting.)

I'm accepting Mark B's answer; the actual answer to the question in the title is simply "yes" :-).

Comment: I suspect the thinking might be that if you reckon `x = x + 1` or `x = x + x` should need a cast in order to explicitly confirm the narrowing of the result, then you shouldn't write `x += 1` or `x += x` at all.

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10916584/274261

Comment: You could use `-Wno-error=conversion` to avoid making the conversion warning an error even with `-Werror`.

Comment: Steve: Yeah, could be, but it's still terribly ugly and I'm hoping there might be a way around the ugliness. Arjun: Yes, I agree that it's related, but for `x` of integral type I think it's more reasonable to want to be able to say `x+=1` than to want to be able to say `x*=0.5`.

Comment: Kenny: Yes, that's true, but we really want our build not to generate any warnings. (Of course I understand that the universe is not obliged to provide us with everything we really want...)

Comment: Now that's a stupid warning! I understand that the types are widen for the operation, but they were initially of type `short`, so it's not a conversion issue (not really), but more an overflow issue and yet if the types were `int` to begin with the possible overflow would not raise any warning at all...

Comment: @Matthieu: agreed, the warning in effect assumes that you always know what you're doing to avoid overflow in `int`, but never know what you're doing to avoid overflow in `short`. As if someone writes `x = x + x` and thinks to themself, "well, the addition is done in an int, so all I need to ensure is that `MIN_INT / 2 <= x <= MAX_INT / 2`" ;-) Promotion to `int` probably made a lot of sense before `long` was invented...

Comment: Matthieu and Steve: Yes, that's the most annoying thing about it.

Comment: Could be worse, at least it doesn't warn for `uint16_t x = 0; x = x & 0xFF;`

Comment: Steve: I think it used to! See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34389 which is complaining about something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the logic for warning in this case is that it's functionally the same as the operation the compound operator implements. Compound operator syntax is supposed to do a very obvious compound operation and in this case you want to explicitly say you know exactly what you're doing. When you want to make it clear that intention exists, spelling out code more explicitly always wins: You're only writing it one time but a longer spelled out version will make it completely clear to future maintainers what your intention was.

I would suggest just de-compounding the operation and spelling out the cast. Your maintainers really won't mind and I doubt they'll think it's ugly.

Alternately, create a `scalar_mult(short&, short)` function to hide away the cast. Then you show explicit intention *and* avoid the cast in every expression.

Finally you might be able to just avoid the shorter types entirely, avoiding the warning.

Comment: I've talked to at least some of the future maintainers, and they do think it's ugly :-). The code in question is going to run in a small embedded system and avoiding the shorter types is not feasible. Replacing `x += y` with something like `add_into(x, y)` is an interesting idea, though. I can't say I *like* it, but I suspect there's going to be no truly likeable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a user-defined type on the RHS would work:

```
struct cast_result {
    int t;
};
char &operator+=(char &l, cast_result r) { return l = static_cast<char>(l + r.t); }

int main() {
    char c = 'a';
    c += cast_result{2};
}
```

You could prettify this a bit with user-defined literals etc., but it's still fairly ugly.

I think it's fair to ask why you need to do arithmetic on narrow types.  It's generally assumed in the design of C that narrow types are or can be less efficient than `int`.

Comment: That's ingenious but horrible :-). Why arithmetic on narrow types? Because we're in a small memory-constrained embedded system with large(ish) arrays of 16-bit values. In some parts of the code it will make sense to do all the actual work on `int`s or `unsigned int`s, converting only on load and store, but not all.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: On those systems, load to `int`, operate on that, and store the result back to `short` (possibly truncating). You can't really do arithmetic on memory anyway, that's what registers are for.

Comment: So you're suggesting that we might "do all the actual work on `int`s or `unsigned int`s, converting only on load and store"? Why yes, that's a good idea. If only I'd thought of that :-). Seriously: you're not wrong; doing arithmetic on types shorter than `int` is generally a really bad sign, and I should probably go over the code to check how much can be reworked to avoid that. (This task is complicated by the fact that some of the actual code is templated C++ that tries to support many integer types simultaneously.)

Comment: +1. I found this one a lot more readable and straightforward than `add_into(x,y)`.